# Can't bind to 'formGroup'

Tags: angular

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Why do I get this error message?

See my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oh1MQL) for live example.

File app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomInputComponent } from './custom-input.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, CustomInputComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

File main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

File app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h2>Testing Angular 2: custom form input</h2>

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <custom-input [name]="city" [formControl]="city"></custom-input>
</form>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private form: FormGroup;
  private city: AbstractControl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'city': 'London'
    });
    this.city = this.form.controls['city']; 
  }

  submit() {
    let formValues = this.form.value;
    console.log('submit',JSON.stringify(formValues));
  }
}
```

File custom-input.compontent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: '<input [name]="name" [id]="name" [formControl]="formControl" type="text">'
})

export class CustomInputComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() formControl: AbstractControl;

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: I see *"No AppModule; making a bare-bones, default AppModule"*, it seems like your module isn't being used.

Comment: I copied the main.ts file from the plunk to the question. The module is used there, so then that is not the problem, right? Or maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: I mean in the Plunkr, in the console

Comment: i think you are missing something like this in your AppComponent. can you check by adding   **form = new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl()
  })**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started building a new Plunker because yours seems not to be properly set up. I also fixed several smaller issues in the code

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/W4IuPbyiQoArwsarBtA2?p=preview)

What's missing is that for a custom element to be used as form control needs to implement `ControlValueAccessor`

Comment: Thanks :) Btw, where did you get the plunker Angular 2 starter setup? Your own or another way?

Comment: Just the `[ New | V ]` button inside the Plunker editor. If you create a new issue in the Angular2 GitHub repo, the issue template also provides a link to a Plunker template (one maintained by the Angular team).

Comment: Thanks again for nice tip :)